# how to get service function with $http response to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1. i want use $http just for my service not controller, can i?
2. so, i got undefined on my console.log when i try to showing my data in a $scope to view.

here my code

```
app.controller('adminControl', ['$scope','$routeParams','$route','adminService', function($scope,$routeParams,$route,adminService){
    $scope.data = adminService.listOfAdmin();
    console.log($scope.data);
}]).service('adminService', ['$http', function($http){
    this.get = function(url){
        return $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:url
        }).then(function(response){
            return response;
        });
    }

    this.listOfAdmin = function(){
        this.get('http://localhost/project/s9/ayu/admin/sys/mac.php?act=administrator')
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a promise and wait for that promise to be fullfilled.

```
app.controller('adminControl', ['$scope','$routeParams','$route','adminService', function($scope,$routeParams,$route,adminService){
    $scope.data = adminService.listOfAdmin().then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    });

}]).service('adminService', ['$http', function($http){
    this.get = function(url){
        return $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:url
        });
    }

    this.listOfAdmin = function(){
        return this.get('http://localhost/project/s9/ayu/admin/sys/mac.php?act=administrator');
    }
}]);
```

Comment: i got output : Array [ Object ] in my console.log. how to show with ng-repeat bro?

Comment: $scope.myArray = response.data; ng-repeat="n in myArray" ??

Comment: Yes, work peffectly, but i changed my controller :
adminService.listOfAdmin().then(function(response){
         $scope.data = response.data;
    });

Thnks

Answer (score 0):

It returns a promise, and the data should be set after the promise is resolved:

```
app.controller('adminControl', ['$scope','$routeParams','$route','adminService', function($scope,$routeParams,$route,adminService){
    adminService.listOfAdmin().then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log($scope.data);
    });

}]).service('adminService', ['$http', function($http){
    this.get = function(url){
        return $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:url
        }).then(function(response){
            return response;
        });
    }

    this.listOfAdmin = function(){
        return this.get('http://localhost/project/s9/ayu/admin/sys/mac.php?act=administrator')
        .then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: i got output : Object { $$state: Object } in console.log. and sure its deferent. I consufed to get this output into my ng-repeat table